# Packed .net core 2.0 application using log4net not working under Ubuntu

Tags: linq, .net-core, ubuntu-14.04, log4net, globalization

I am not able to execute my C# **.Net Core 2.0** application on ubuntu14.04 other than installing the .net core SDK and use dotnet run. The application uses **log4net 2.0.8** which is causing the problems. When I pack it using **dotnet publish -c Release -r ubuntu.14.04-x64** on WIndows 10 I get lots of errors like:

`error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.Runtime.Extensions from 4.3.0 to 4.1.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
...
error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.Runtime.InteropServices from 4.3.0 to 4.1.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.`

Referencing these packages directly does not change anything but packing it under linux is working. However, when i execute the packed app using ./maypp I get:

`` Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: SafeHandle cannot be null.
Parameter name: pHandle
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.SafeHandleAddRef(SafeHandle pHandle, Boolean& success)
   at Interop.GlobalizationInterop.GetSortKey(SafeSortHandle sortHandle, String str, Int32 strLength, Byte* sortKey, Int32 sortKeyLength, CompareOptions options)
   at System.Globalization.CompareInfo.GetHashCodeOfStringCore(String source, CompareOptions options, Boolean forceRandomizedHashing, Int64 additionalEntropy)
   at System.Linq.Set1.InternalGetHashCode(TElement value)
   at System.Linq.Set1.Add(TElement value)
   at System.Linq.Set1.UnionWith(IEnumerable1 other)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.DistinctIterator1.FillSet()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.DistinctIterator1.ToArray()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) ``

Without log4net it is working. Google did not reveal any hint. Any Ideas are welcome?

Comment: are you referencing maybe both packages ```Microsoft.AspNetCore.All``` and ```Microsoft.NetCore.App``` ?
I had very similar issues related to this as the ```Microsoft.NetCore.App``` should not be referenced directly. Because of this i had some version mismatch looking quite the same. Also  the problem described here resulted in my case in similar problens https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/476

Answer (score 0):

I solved (workaround?) the problem by doing an apt-get install libicu52 and not use the "System.Globalization.Invariant": true in the .runtimeconfig.json